# ggplot + spss multiple response variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks somewhat like this:

```r
data <- data.frame (id = c(1,2,3), V1 = c(2,3,4), V2 = c(1,2,3), Group = c(1,2,1))
```

V1 and V2 are actually 2 characteristics of the same variable, let's say variable V.

I am trying to make a ggplot where I can actually visualize how many V variables I have present on my population, filtered by variable group. But this gets tricky since I don't want to double account responses (2 times some V characteristic but still only 1 person has it not 2)

After actually having this solved how can ggplot show the actual label stored on the spss instead of values 1,2,3,etc.

Comment: Use the `haven` package to read in your SPSS formatted data so that the labels are present in R.

Comment: Thanks will have to check haven further for that part of the matter.